# Scripts for migrating Distribution Groups from Lotus Notes to AD/Exchange

Tags: powershell, active-directory, lotus-notes

it's nice to meet you!

I need your help in a simple matter, but a complex one for a beginner.

I'm trying to migrate some distribution/security groups from IBM Lotus Notes to Active Directory, in order to ease group managing. I do know that I'll have to:

1. Create the target group in Active Directory with the same name as the exchange contact;
2. Add to the new AD group all members contained in the old Notes group;
3. Insert attributes in AD Group, such as mail address, proxy, friendly name, etc;
4. Delete the contact on AD/Exchange;

My problem here is that I have too many groups and too little time. **Less than a month and more than 1100 groups**. A co-worker told me that there's the possibility of migrating the groups via Powershell script. However, I have no idea where or how to start. I've never written any script other than the one-liner "Shutdown -s -t 1600" to save it as a .bat, let alone a migration script on powershell. I do however, have some experience with AD.

Can anyone help me with where to start? Is there a way to do that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Start with opening ISE. Learn the basics of variables, arrays, loops. Export that data to a csv file (if possible) and `Import-Csv`. Understand how to access certain columns based on the properties of the object you've created from importing to a variable. `Get-ADUser` against the domain controller you're working with. Try `Set-ADUser -WhatIf` to learn what it's like to change fields. Then slap it all together. Start small and build up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check into it.

Comment: Found a way to do it. Didn't import CSV yet, as it's still hard to treat the data. However, found a way to create multiple groups and set attributes to them. Can't add multiple users from CSV though. Any tips?